# Is it possible to let emacs verilog-auto connect wires which are templated in AUTO_TEMPLATE

Tags: emacs, verilog

When using AUTOINST in emacs verilog-mode auto, it will try to connect all ports listed in .v. Is it possible to let emacs verilog-mode auto only connect ports which are templated at AUTO_TEMPLATE when using AUTOWIRE / AUTOOUTPUT / AUTOINPUT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question/feature request to post at https://www.veripool.org/wiki/verilog-mode

Mac

Answer (score 0):

You can use **AUTO_TEMPLATE** with .* instead of using **AUTOINST** , and that will do what you're asking. This assumes you're okay with the dot-star behavior